# Powershell can't execute binary file

Tags: powershell, git

I recently installed RabbitMQ on my system and was trying to enable a plugin functionality. This is the command I used (as per their docs):

```
./rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

**rabbitmq-plugins** is a file in a folder:

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\escript
```

On running the line a dialogue opens up asking "How do you want to open this file?"

I tried running it via Git Bash with no luck as well. After tinkering about and setting erlang in path and some RabbitMQ specific environment variables I got stuck at:

```
Error: :no_plugins_file
```

Powershell still exhibits the same behavior. I even used Set-ExecutionPolicy to give unrestricted access to the CurrentUser as well as the LocalMachine. No change.

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq should have a rabbitmq-plugins.bat file in \rabbitmq_server-x.x.x\sbin. Execute that file instead of the binary:

```
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
```

see: https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-windows/